# Center of momentum frame for two dimensions

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, photons, mass-energy, pair-production

I have been investigating the scenario of two photons traveling in space (in a lab frame of reference) of different frequencies are about to collide with an angle $\theta$ between them. I set their 4-momentum vectors to be $(hν_1/c , hν_1/c \cos(\theta) ,hν_1/c \sin(\theta), 0)$ for a gamma photon and $(hν_2/c , hν_2/c , 0 , 0)$ for a CMB photon. I am having a hard time figuring out what the energy would be in a zero momentum frame due to the angle. The pair production along with a Lorentz transformation lead me to believe that $hν_1/c \sin(\theta)$ would always equal zero which is hard to believe as I can adjust the angle in other frames.

Comment: Do photons interact like this? I’ve never heard of a photon-photon “collision”.

Comment: It is used to create matter, making positron and electron similar to the Breit-Wheeler process.

Comment: Thanks. Didn’t know that was possible.

Comment: As far as i know this is not directly possible, only through some higher-order effects. But I guess this is valid as an approximation or an exercise.

Comment: I am doing it as an exercise. I am thinking of that, but there has to be a way to transition a system of photons to a center of momentum frame.

It is the reverse of pair antihalation.

Comment: @Ben51 The pi0 decays into two photons. see in addition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set c=1, and, so $h\nu=E=p$, much less cluttered. Assuming you are serious about the signs you have chosen, the total energy, momentum four vector in the lab frame is
$$
(p_1+p_2, p_2+ p_1 \cos\theta, p_1\sin\theta, 0).
$$
In the center of momentum frame, $(E,0,0,0)$. But $s=E^2-\vec{p}^2$ is a relativistic invariant, and so the same in both frames, so
$$
E^2= 2p_1p_2 (1-\cos\theta),
$$
with a minimum at 0, and a maximum at 4$p_1p_2$. This is the smallest energy squared at which a pair of particles of mass *m* will be produced at rest,
where $m^2=p_1p_2$.